# css3 image fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have images fade in with css3 once they're loaded. The problem is the way my methods are currently chained it fades it in and out for a split second twice. instead of just being blank and fading in.

my solution was to try and split out the animation code into a seperate class that i apply AFTER i initially set the opacity to zero (i do this in JS so people without js enabled can still see the images).

It's still not working though

I assume its because in this code its setting the opacity to zero and immediately adding an animation transition class which somehow catches the opacity .css() method while its changing still (dont know how this is possible,... shouldnt it complete opacity before moving on to add class?)

```
// nice thumbnail loading
$('.thumb').css('opacity','0').addClass('thumb-animated').on('load', function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
});   


.resources .thumb-animated {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
       -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .2s;
         -o-transition: opacity .2s;
            transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

Why do you set opacity to 1 in jQuery?
If you want to use CSS3 and not simply fadeIn(200) why don't you add "opacity: 1" to css class thumb-animated?

**EDIT:**

Note that load will not be triggered if the image is already in cache.
Also, `!important` has to be added to rewrite the rule modified via javascript.

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/enTCe/5/
This seems to work perfectly outside JSfiddle, on JSfiddle looks like it waits for all the images to be loaded.

Comment: I dont want them to wait for them all to load either, theres like 100 images. I'd like each image to load when it finishes (giving an almost 'checkerboard' effect)

Comment: i like that you took into account cache though, i noticed when it loads the first time it works and when you refresh it acts funky. i assumed that had to do with the cache. do you think you could revise that fiddle and ill mark yours as teh accepted answer? :)

Comment: It's because of JSfiddle. Try doing so locally, here's an example (download file and open it) https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6808501/fisier.html

Comment: First 2 images are in cache, the other 4 aren't.

Comment: sorry, i didnt see your last comment btw before i clicked it, about it not working in jsfiddle. :o thanks!

Comment: thats great about the cache. i didnt know you coudl do that. could you explain a little how that works?

Comment: Well, there are actually 2 different things: 1) For each image check if loading is already completed, if it is completed than trigger the "load" method. 2) Every time load is triggered show the image. Now "load" is either triggered after the image is actually loaded, or triggered by the call inside the each loop (the one that checks for already-loaded images)

Answer (score 1):

What about using just css animations? No JS code is needed.

```
        @-webkit-keyframes opacityChange {
            0%   { opacity: 0; }
            100% { opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes opacityChange {
            0%   { opacity: 0; }
            100% { opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes opacityChange {
            0%   { opacity: 0; }
            100% { opacity: 1; }
        }
        .thumb {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-animation: opacityChange 5s;
            -moz-animation:    opacityChange 5s;
            -ms-animation:     opacityChange 5s;
        }
```

Comment: Awesome approach but problem is that it doesn't run the animation on img load. All thumbnails run animation moment first thumb been loaded...

Answer (score 0):

You can wait adding the class to the image is loaded

```
$('.thumb').css('opacity','0').on('load', function(){
    $(this).addClass('thumb-animated').css('opacity','1');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$('#thumb').hide();

myImg = $('<img>').attr('src', 'thumb.png').load(function(){
    $('#thumb').html(myImg).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use fadein for performance issues. It's a lot of images